# PHP Timestamp conversion to Date not working

Tags: php, date, timestamp

Can anyone please explain me this weird behaviour of these timestamps?
There's an application that converts the timestamps to dates like this:

```
1184947071570 - 07-20-2007 11:57
```

```
1190394533377 - 09-21-2007 13:08
```

I cannot access the source code of that application. But I got the timestamps from the database, and when I convert to date using php this is what happens:

```
1184947071570 - 20 April 1955 13:17:54
```

```
1190394533377 - 27 October 1991 14:39:45
```

I used this code in php:

```
date("l, j F Y H:i:s", $timestamp)
```

The dates are completely different! How can I get the correct dates??

Thank you.

Comment: There's no way anyone will know what is causing this behavior without seeing code.

Comment: Are you sure these timestamps are definitely standard Unix timestamps? The first one points to a day in a year 39519.

Comment: your calculation isn't correct either TIME STAMP: 1184947071570

DATE (M/D/Y @ h:m:s): 06 / 24 / 19 @ 10:19:30pm EST

Comment: ummm...the first time stamp (with your code) is giving me Tuesday, 24 June 39519 23:19:30. The second is giving me Wednesday, 6 February 39692 07:09:37. Where are you getting 1955 and 1991 from?

Comment: $time1 = 1184947071570;
    $time2 = 1190394533377;

    echo date("l, j F Y H:i:s", $time1)."<br />";
    echo date("l, j F Y H:i:s", $time2);

This was the code I used to get my result. What are you using?

Comment: s.lenders Not correct? What code did you use?? Using this date("l, j F Y H:i:s", 1184947071570); gives me 20 April 1955 13:17:54

Comment: 1184947071570 is a 41bit number, e.g. larger than a standard 32bit signed unix timestamp. no wonder you're getting wonky results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The timestamps you have include milliseconds. If you divide your timestamps by 1000 you will get the correct times.

```
echo date('l, j F Y H:i:s', 1184947071570 / 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

They are not seconds like UNIX timestamps.

They are milliseconds devide it by 1000 and try again

Answer (score 0):

I've just made some tests and your db timestamp has some additional characters.

Timestamp for `07-20-2007 11:57` is `1184947020`